# how to get a snapshot of just the dates in my firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I want to make a list of dates from the snapshot I get in my firebase database. However when I type the code:

```
System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

I get the whole snapshot:
 {Date : 2018 - 04 - 11={-L9pZ0HYpBjmvMEL430k={downloadURL="https:...."}

I just want to get a snapshot of the children of dates.

Answer (score 0):

From your snapshot you have to get your child and your element just like this :

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("IndexOfYourDatabse"); //Init your ref at Data
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                       
            String date = messageSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString(); //acces to child => date
            System.out.println(date);
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Get date from your object

```
                mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(whatever);

                mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Person person = snapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                            date = person.getDate();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Creating a hashmap allowed me to get the key values, which were the dates I needed to put in my listview.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(keys.get(i));


            }





        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```